# How can I queue a script to run the next time a system is up and connected to the internet?

Tags: script, cron, connection, daemon, queue

I'm using [mailsend](https://github.com/muquit/mailsend/) (on a Mac) to send mail from the command line.  I'd like to set this up such that I can execute a send command, but if my system is disconnected from the internet, that command is queued up until the next time the system is available.  As it stands, mailsend exits with an error--

It seems I'm looking for something like [anacron](http://anacron.sourceforge.net/), but for internet connectivity *and* system uptime.  It seems likely I could use something like [daemonize](http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/), but it's not clear to me how to establish a queue as opposed to simply not running a command if I'm not connected.  I'm not attached to using mailsend, but I'd like as simple a solution as possible that doesn't involve setting up my own MTA (*i.e.* probably not `sendmail` *et al*).

Comment: I'm a little confused with the situation. What happens if you `send` and the system is not connected? Doesn't it get queued? And sent upon connection? Do you exit your application and can only send if application is running?

Comment: Clarified!  Right now `mailsend` exits with an error--

Comment: Setting up an MTA generally _is_ the simple solution. Why is your Mac server having Internet connectiivty issues?

Comment: It's not, I'm using this on my local machine, so maybe I should just set up mutt and be done with it.